# How does this Javascript .map() function works?

Tags: javascript

I found a function for the running sum of an array in javascript.

```
const runningSum = function(nums) {
  return nums.map((acc = 0, num => acc += num));
};
```

For my understanding and according to the definition from MDN is acc := currentValue and num:= Index. But how does that work with the arrow function inside the parameters?
I appreciate any help or explantions

Comment: I think you are confusing reduce and map. What you shared makes little sense.

Comment: Note the extra set of parenthesis. It's a really unintuitive way of writing: ```const runningSum = function(nums) {
  acc = 0; return nums.map(num => acc += num);
};``` (Note that implicit globals are awful too).

Comment: @Evert It makes sense, it's just a very unorthodox way (and arguably wrong way) of writing this…